# 2sxc TimelineJS thumbnails failing? PagePeeker.com API issues?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a new deploy of the latest version of TimelineJS app running on 2sxc 9.42 and for reasons I can't seem to figure out or find any useful errors on this, the api.pagepeeker.com seems to be failing or not getting used. You can see at the link below that it has worked sometimes, but as you progress to the later entities, it just gives up and displays the URL for the media without trying to create a thumbnail. 
https://www.glencoeparkdistrict.com/News/Special-Projects/Timeline

I have tried restarting the app pool, clearing the cache and deleting and re-adding the items, but am unable to get things working as expected. Is there some way to force the API to retry getting the initial thumbnail?

How can I debug this or get a handle on what is going wrong here?

Comment: I can't see any pointers to sites - could you specify a date or two to look at?

Comment: Note that you're also using HUGE images - 10MB and more. Best let it run through a resizer or something.

Comment: If you know a way 'in the moment' to control what the client does, please let me know. This is a great example of where ADAM/ImageResizing being able to set an initial size at point of upload would literally save the planet. Well, at least the Internetz! ;) 
  
In house, we have good processes in place to always pre-process images to a max of 8 megapixels (or 3266 long side), but getting clients to do this has been 0 in 100+ (valiant and well intentioned) efforts.

Comment: I haven't looked at it a lot, but the 2sxc-data is passed to timelinejs, so if you modify that part a bit to change the urls and add a ?w=800 or something you should be good to go.